# Customize QAGenerateChain prompt in langchain

Tags: langchain, gpt-3

I want to customize the prompt of QAGenerateChain. However, the function doesn't accept the argument of the prompt. how can I change the following with my prompt?

`from langchain.evaluation.qa import QAGenerateChain

example_gen_chain = QAGenerateChain.from_llm(llm)
`

I  tries to modify the class